# How do I get MMS working on Nexus 5 with Straight Talk?

Tags: nexus-5

I can't send or receive MMS messages via Straight Talk on my Nexus 5.  I've verified that my wife's iPhone works just fine with the same information, as well as verifying that MMS used to work on my Nexus 4 with the generic ST instructions.

- I've already verified that I have the most recent SIM card from ST
- I've already verified that using the standard ST info for the APN does not work.

```
APN Name: Straight Talk
APN: tfdata
Port: 80
MMSC: http://mms-tf.net
MMS Proxy: mms3.tracfone.com
MMS Port: 80
```

- I waited for a billing cycle to pass in case it would just fix itself after a billing cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally hit upon APN settings which did the trick for me.

```
APN Name: STRAIGHT_TALK
APN: tfdata
Port: 80
Username: not set
Password: not set
Server: not set
MMSC: http://mms-tf.net
MMS Proxy: 66.209.11.33
MMS Port: 80
MCC: 310
MNC: 410
Auth Type: none
APN Type: default,supl,mms,hipri,agps,fota,dun,entitle
```

Comment: If you have found the solution, please mark this answer as solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with my Nexus 5 not sending MMS messages and it turned out the pictures were just to big. I downloaded an app called Go SMS Pro (it's free) and it automatically re-sizes it, and it fixed the issue.